# Apache Reverse Proxy : put a htaccess type password on a specfic URL

Tags: reverse-proxy, .htaccess, apache2

I have an Apache2 reverse proxy managing multiple domains.

Inside I have a vHost configured like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        RewriteEngine On
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges
        ProxyPass / http://10.55.0.180/plugin/main/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.55.0.180/plugin/main/
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
            Allow from All
        </Directory>
        <Location /Cours/index.php/Stats/>
                  AuthType Basic
                  AuthName "Wrapper auth"
                  AuthBasicProvider file
                  AuthUserFile "/etc/.htpasswd"
                  Require valid-user
        </Location>
```

The purpose of this is that users accessing `https://www.example.com` can do it without being prompted for a password whereas those who access `https://www.example.com/Cours/index.php/Stats/` can't do it without being authenticated.

Of course, if I'm there, this method is not working.

The `/etc/.htpasswd` file is present and well configured but people are able to access `https://www.example.com/Cours/index.php/Stats/` without being asked for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. My issue was the trailing slash at the end of the location as it is automatically remove at the end of the URL in the browser. So this is the working config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        RewriteEngine On
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges
        ProxyPass / http://10.55.0.180/plugin/main/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.55.0.180/plugin/main/
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
            Allow from All
        </Directory>
        <Location /Cours/index.php/Stats>
                  AuthType Basic
                  AuthName "Wrapper auth"
                  AuthBasicProvider file
                  AuthUserFile "/etc/.htpasswd"
                  Require valid-user
        </Location>
```